# How do I get rid of the error system.null reference exception object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: vb.net

I get an error when i read data in a Null or empty cell in a datagridview to enable me send the data to a fiscal printer

Here is the part of the code

```
ke.PrintRecMessage("--------------------------------------------")

ke.PrintRecMessage("ITEM QTY PRICE AMOUNT")

ke.PrintRecMessage("--------------------------------------------")


Dim max1 As Integer = Qualitix_POS.Form1.DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1

For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Qualitix_POS.Form1.DataGridView1.Rows


ke.PrintRecItem(Description:=row.Cells("Column2").Value,
Price:=row.Cells("Column4").Value,
Quantity:=row.Cells("Column3").Value.ToString.PadRight(4, "0"),
VatInfo:=row.Cells("Column6").Value, UnitPrice:=row.Cells("Column4").Value,
UnitName:=row.Cells("Column1").Value)

Next
```

Comment: Something in your code is returning a null value, and it’s difficult to know what just from the code snippet. You’re going to have to debug the code, stepping through it and inspecting the values of each variable/property. Once you know what is null you can code defensively around it, i.e. check if it is null before trying to do something with it.

Comment: For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Qualitix_POS.Form1.DataGridView1.Rows

                If row.Cells("Column2").Value Is Nothing Then

                    Return

                End If

                ke.PrintRecItem(Description:=row.Cells("Column2").Value, Price:=row.Cells("Column4").Value.ToString, Quantity:=row.Cells("Column3").Value.ToString.PadRight(4, "0"), VatInfo:=Convert.ToString(row.Cells("Column6").Value), UnitPrice:=Convert.ToString(row.Cells("Column4").Value), UnitName:="")

            Next

Comment: I have added above lines  to check if a cell is null so the error is not popping up again but i cannot print successfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a check in the loop

```
if row <> nothing then
...
end if
```

If that doesnt help, we have some wrappers in our code that return empty string if the response is null

```
wrapString(myvar.getName())
```

Will return the name or "" same for wrapInt etc

Comment: Theresa Forster Accepted the answer